# HTTP Status code for when client is outside the allowed IP subnet

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have a web application that can be accessed only if the client accessing the application is within a group of allowed subnets.

If not, I want to redirect to a page with an appropriate HTTP header. The HTTP status that seems most obvious to me for this purpose is a `403 Forbidden`.

I am currently using:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
```

However, is this the ideal status code for the scenario described?

Comment: IMHO 403 should be used.

Comment: Seems best to me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to redirect to a page with an appropriate HTTP header

Don't redirect. Just return the error response for the URL that was requested. ("You can find `/foo` at `/error`" … "You aren't allowed to read `/error`" doesn't make much sense).

> is this the ideal status code for the scenario described

The [definition of 403](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.

Which matches your scenario, so yes, use that.

Answer (score 2):

**403 Forbidden** seems like the most descriptive status code for this. However, [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) suggests that you could also use **404 Not Found** if you don't want to let the user know that the reason for the failure is an access control restriction. It says:

> If ... the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

If the person attempting the access believes the error code, it might discourage them from trying to find a way around the restriction (e.g. by searching for a proxy). But it probably won't stop a determined hacker.